# How to get latest blockly version on node

Tags: blockly, google-blockly

I have installed Blockly on Node using the following command

npm install blockly

it got installed, but its older version 1.0.0 published on 2016.
How will i  get new latest version of blockly on Node. Please any one post what to do or how to install

Note: Can i paste latest code on node-module directly via explorer .

Comment: Hi All, 
 I have got an answer in Blockly group ,If any one needed please have a look at following link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/blockly/9fBA0_IbT7g

You can directly install from the Git which has latest version 

`npm install git://github.com/google/blockly.git#1.20181219.0`

Answer (score 1):

Blockly has now Published officialy in NPM

Regarding this you can check in following url: https://www.npmjs.com/package/blockly

Samples are available under following link : https://github.com/google/blockly-samples

If you need more detail you can check in Blockly Group : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/blockly-announce/8CyW3M8_mc0

Answer (score 0):

If any one need clear understanding over NPM on blockly check the video from blockly summit

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WfUpbJ-I4qE&list=PLSIUOFhnxEiDpgF62jkfdSYGGhK-pe3tL&index=17